# How can I remove history from a bzr branch, or create a branch for a tagged release that does not contain project history?

Tags: version-control, release, bazaar

I would like to create a project branch that represents a stable release. I have followed the [tag and export instructions](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/latest/en/user-guide/releasing_a_project.html) described in the 'releasing a project' section of the bazaar manual, but this does not appear to create a new branch (i.e. there are no contents to the checkout).

My primary goals are to a) give developers the ability to submit changes to this branch while b) removing existing history.

Is there a way to do this in bazaar?

Comment: Why do you want to remove existing history?

Comment: @dOxxx because it is a mess - I was learning how to code as I wrote the package and I would prefer to release the first version without all of the mess. Anyone who would want to work with me could branch from the development branch, which would include all the detailed history, but at least I could have control over / knowledge of who sees it.

Comment: Your other option is to create a new repo/branch from an export and use this for your own development from now on. It means you lose all of your prior history but it sounds like you may not care much about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bzr tag` defines a more descriptive identifier for a particular revision so that you can easily refer to that revision, e.g. when you are exporting a particular revision of your project for release.

`bzr export` exports the contents of the working tree as it stands at the specified revision. The exported contents are not under revision control.

If you want to create a branch from that tag, you can use `bzr branch -rtag:TAGNAME original_branch new_branch` but that does not remove existing history.

You could use `bzr export -rtag:TAGNAME /some/directory` and then `bzr init` in `/some/directory` to create a new branch with no existing history, but starting with the contents of that particular revision.

Comment: I thought of that, and perhaps this is the only way to do this, but it has the undesired effect of splitting the trunk into two separate units that would (presumably) make it more difficult to merge down the line.

Comment: bzr requires a common ancestor revision for merging, so if you want to be able to merge back into your original branch, you'll have to branch from the tag so that it includes the history.